# Can't make an exact match of a string in a txt file

Tags: python, regex

i solved a lot of questions by reading your posts but now i'm stuck at the following.

My problem is that i can't make an absolute match of a given word in my txt file.
I wrote the following:

```
for word in listtweet:
    #print word,
    pattern=re.compile(r'\b%s\b' %(word))
    with open('testsentiwords_fullTotal_clean1712.txt', 'r') as f:
        for n,line in enumerate(f):
            if pattern.search(line):
                    print 'found word: ', word, 'in line ', line
```

My output is partly correct:

> > found word dirty in line '-0.458333333333', 'dirty'

But i also get:

> > found word dirty in line '-0.5', 'dirty-minded'
> >
> > found word dirty in line '-0.625', 'dirty-faced'

I only want to get the exact match and nothing more!
Pls any help?

Comment: Your code does not match up with your output.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse CSV. Luckily there is a module for that!

Answer (score 2):

Try with this pattern :

```
pattern=re.compile(r'[^-a-zA-Z]%s[^-a-zA-Z]' %(word))
```

The problem with your pattern is that the '-' character is in \b.

If you need numbers in your word, you can add 0-9 to this pattern.

```
pattern=re.compile(r'[^-a-zA-Z0-9]%s[^-a-zA-Z0-9]' %(word))
```

Comment: sorry but don't understand how to pass this pattern. The word i'm checking is coming from a list so how i write [a-z] while i'm searching for a particular word? %s (i'm really a new in python:-)

Comment: @tsakati : Ok my fault ! Hadn't understood well what you were asking. In fact, in your pattern, if %s is the word you're looking for, you need to replace \b by [^-a-zA-Z]. I edited my post :)

Comment: thnks for the answers but still get words that i don't want       >>>found word last in line '-0.25', 'stay', 'last_out', 'ride_out', 'outride'

Answer (score 0):

If the print output you provide shows the actual lines in the file (where the word you're looking for is always enclosed in single quotes), I think that your re pattern wants to be like

```
p = re.compile(r"'%s'" % target_word)
```

so results would be something like:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r"'%s'" % "dirty")
>>> p.search("'12345', 'dirty'")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x631b10>
>>> p.search("'12345', 'dirty-faced'")
>>>
```

Comment: thnks for your reply and you are right all the words that i'm looking for are enclosed in single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, switch from `\b` to check for word boundaries to `[^-a-zA-Z]`, since `-` counts as a word boundary. Secondly, if you have long lines, consider using the `in` keyword first:

```
if word in line and pattern.search(line):
```

that way python can do a fast match for the letters of the word first before deploying the regular expression engine. Should speed things up for large files where most lines do not match at all.

Thirdly, fix your code sample - printing `line` will print the line contents, whereas printing `n` (or better yet ``n`` to convert to a string).

Fourth, consider using grep instead:

```
grep -nwf needles_on_separate_lines haystack.txt
```

Which will do all you want, and far faster than Python.

Comment: thnks for the tips. I have to do it with python.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `\b` matches at word boundaries. These are defined as "a position between an alphanumeric character and a non-alphanumeric character".

So `\bdirty\b` will match `dirty` in the string `This is dirty!` but not in `dirtying your clothes`. So far so good, but since `-` is also a non-alphanumeric character, `\b` will also trigger in `dirty-minded` as you observed.

What you therefore need to do is to think about what characters you do not want to allow as word-separators. If it's only the dash, you could add another pair of assertions to exclude those:

```
r"(?<!-)\b%s\b(?!-)" % word
```

If you want to add more characters to exclude as valid word boundaries, for example the apostrophe, use a character class:

```
r"(?<!['-])\b%s\b(?!['-])" % word
```

Comment: i did that but i get the following error

>>> 
found word sad in line '-0.583333333333', 'sad', 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Twitter\MyTwitterFolder_PythonFilesWork_17122010\ScorTweets\FindScoreTweet_2.py", line 25, in <module>
    pattern=re.compile(r"(?<!-)\b%s\b(?!-)" %word)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: unbalanced parenthesis
>>>

Comment: Well, it works here, but there seems to be an unbalanced parenthesis in your expression somewhere. You do not happen to have a word that contains parentheses in your word list?

Comment: a sample of my wordlist ['mcglamorous;', 'sad', 'last', 'like', 'u', '&', 'did', 'fabulous', 'job', 'even', 'w/out', 'our', 'entourage!', ':)', 'merry', 'christmas']

Comment: i did it!!!! i just put a control (if word.isalpha()) just after the first loop and before the pattern and seems to work!!!

Comment: Well, `:)` will give you the "unbalanced parenthesis" error, and the `\b` word boundaries will only work around actual words, not around strings that contain non-word characters.